# Soft keyboard doesn't show fullscreen when hidding navigation bar

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My app runs on a 7 inch tablet in kiosk mode, and for that I'm using
`service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui` to hide navigation bar.
Everything is going well except for the soft keyboard which continues to have the app usable width (the width of the tablet minus the width of the nav bar).
My device is running an Android api level 19.

Please check picture below
[image]

Comment: Still no answer so far? :( I'm in trouble with this issue, pls anyone if you know a fix...Thank you

Comment: Hello @gabrjela, have you resolve this issue?